# Can I get nativefier to produce a .deb?

Tags: application-development, deb, packaging, electron

On macOS and Windows, the Electron JS app creator script `nativefier` is able to wrap a website into a `.dmg` or `.exe`.  However, on `Ubuntu`, the `nativefier` script produces a big folder where you have to create a `.desktop` file, which is annoying.  Is there a way to get a `.deb` from the script?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 20.04, if relevant